# How should I flag this question?

Tags: discussion, flagging

**This question should be removed in my opinion:** https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/77868/how-to-remove-a-vedum-halo-bathroom-light

---

**The question if it does get deleted so everybody can see it, not just high rep users:**

*How to remove a Vedum Halo bathroom light [on hold]*

> We have a wall mounted Vedum Halo bathroom light with 4 spots.
>
> We would like to take it down and replace it. There is a small top
>   plate that I can remove and disconnect the power wires.
>
> But I cannot see how the light is fixed to the wall. There are no
>   visible screws.
>
> Anyone know how to get it down?

It's about how to get a bathroom light from the ceiling, nothing to do with electronics *at all*. That user having almost 2K rep on SO.SE I hoped that they would figure it out themselves, but I also decided to flag the post. However, **there wasn't a flag that applied *at all*.**

So the obvious route to flag: **It doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate > Off-topic because... > ???**

---

**The options:**

- > Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to
  >   purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and
  >   quickly obsolete. Instead, describe your situation and the specific
  >   problem you're trying to solve.

  Not really a shopping question so not this one.
- > Questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic as this site
  >   is intended specifically for questions on electronics design.

  Not really either, but it *would* work. However, I think that it should be on DIY.SE, not EE.SE. So I proceed down the list.
- > Questions on appliance repair are off-topic unless they involve
  >   specific troubleshooting steps and demonstrate a good understanding of
  >   the underlying design of the device being repaired. See: Is asking on
  >   how to fix a faulty circuit on topic?

  Not really an appliance, but if it was considered an appliance, it would fall under this category.
- > This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

  You can only choose Meta.EE.SE or Super User. Both won't work.

So the best choices: appliance repair or use, not design. **It is not really either.** If I could say that it belongs on DIY.SE, then I would, but there isn't an option. **What should I have done?**

(It is closed/on hold now, but I'm asking what I should have flagged it for.)

Comment: I wish DIY.SE was an available suggested migration path. This is not the first time a question that would fit in fine on DIY, showed up on EE.SE.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh I do too. Skip having a process to add another site to that list. There should be a "More" button at the bottom so you can move it anywhere on SE. This is a real pain.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh Do you think I should add one to Meta.SO or is it already there? There also needs to be a "None of the above"

Comment: Add what to Meta.SO? There already is http://DIY.stackexchange.com/ if that is what you mean. Yes, "Some other SE site entirely", with a prompt for "which one" would be awesome.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh I know there is a DIY.SE. I would have gone to Area 51, not Meta.SO though... I'll see if it's there and post it if it's not. EDIT: it is... status declined so the user isn't hit with 200 different sites to choose from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is to expand on the comment by Anindo Ghosh **.

For the time being, I  would flag a post like that with a custom message *"migration candidate for DIY.SE"*.

I too wish that DIY.SE (and mechanics.SE) was in the migration options (like SuperUser already is).  We have a [meta thread dedicated to expanding migration options](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2842/7036).  Perhaps, we should re-run the 90-day statistics in the beginning of September and request DIY.SE to be added to the migration list.  The ploy here is that summer is the primary season for construction and home improvement.  (At least in the N. hemisphere it is.)

** +1, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

I'd simply close vote it as OT vis a vis appliance repair (the reason why it's OT), and flag for attention for migration to DIY, maybe adding a comment that that's what I did.