# Close for migration options

Tags: discussion, feature-request

The choices under migration seem to me to be a constantly moving target.  I understand completely why the choices need to be limited, but leaving a close voter no option for "other" under migration, to be filled in as text, means to continue one must back out of the APPROPRIATE migration section to a more general OTHER choice.  Can OTHER be added to migration options??

Comment: Migrating a post can be useful, but let's keep in perspective that if you don't want your post closed as apposed to migrated to a more appropriate site, you should post it at the appropriate site in the first place.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but just judging by my own behavior, when I want to suggest a migration, and I drill down to the right point only to find no appropriate option, I often abandon the close instead of undrilling and getting back to the general "other".  I'd be a better custodian if things were just a tad bit smoother, and I'm betting my behavior isn't all that rare.  I put this up as a suggestion only after finding myself in the same situation about a half dozen times.

Comment: If one close reason is too much hassle (as off topic is often for me), just close for some other reason. If SE wants us to be more accurate, stop making it difficult to be accurate. As for the moron who couldn't be bothered to read the rules before blurting out his inappropriate question, he might get the wrong idea why it was closed. Oh well. If you don't want your question closed, don't write a bad question (duh).  Having close be a kick in the butt is a Good Thing.

Comment: I totally agree that the UI is frustrating in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

We have a mechanism which provides the "other" migration option.  Rather than (or in addition to) closing the post, you can make a moderator flag with a custom "other" message (at the very bottom of the list.  The message could be along the lines of:

> *migration candidate for mechanics.SE (vehicle maintenance stack)*

I post such flags regularly, and the questions do get migrated sometimes**, so these flags do get processed by the mods.

See also [this thread on meta](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2800/more-migration-options).  It's dedicated to expanding migration options.

________
** Migration is multi-stage process, which depends on a lot of things.

Comment: That doesn't pass usability muster.  You migrate all the way down a close path only to find that you have to back out and start again.  There isn't even an indication in the menu what to do if the group you recommend migration to doesn't appear.  "You have to know how" just isn't an acceptable path.