# Add a migration path to the Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange

Tags: feature-request, migration, flagging

I encountered [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/120648/wiringpi-vs-default-raspbian-rpi-gpio-module) today and it clearly is better suited for the raspberry pi stack exchange.  So I searched on how to flag it to be moved and encountered [this question](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/882/how-to-migrate-questions-from-stackoverflow)  which the answer states that a stack exchange is only allowed to have 5 migration paths.  So I went hrough the process of flagging for migration and it turns out Electrical Engineering only has two migration paths.

Seeing as how the RaspberryPi is closely related to Electrical Engineering, we are no doubt going to get questions that should be on the Raspberry Pi exchange rather than the Electrical Engineering one.

Can we get a migration path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If something lacks a migration path, simply flag it for moderator attention and describe where and why in the flag note.

Also, StackExchange policy is not to migrate to betas, even though EE breaks that often with RPI and Ardunio Betas :/

Comment: Wait, why wouldn't policy let us do that?  That is completely round-about.  We'd have to send it to alpha exchange and then to a beta?  That's just silly

Comment: @ShannonStrutz what do you mean send it to alpha exchange? The SE policy is simply that almost nothing should be migrated to a beta site. Not that it has to go through another site.

Comment: I mean through stack-exchange meta or super-user or something and then down to Rpi

Comment: @ShannonStrutz like I said, simply flag it. It's almost the same thing as a close vote.

Comment: Okay, thats what I plan on doing.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't mind having a migration path<sup>1</sup> for RaspberryPi.SE.  But I'm not sure that we can get one<sup>2</sup> , because RaspberryPi.SE is still in beta.  The statistics shows that we have migrated eight (8) threads over there in the last 90 days.

In the mean time, please don't hesitate to flag threads if you think that they should be migrated.

<sup>1</sup> Similar to what we have for SuperUser.
<sup>2</sup> Addition of a migration paths is done by SE mods (higher level than us stack mods).
<sup>3</sup> Here's a [year-old thread](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2842/7036) about expanding migration options.

**edit:**

This guideline of not migrating to betas is just one of the handful of migration guidelines.  It came about, because migrated questions go live up at the destination stack immediately (there is no quarantine buffer), so a beta can potentially get swamped with migrations.

1. A beta can not be one of the *Off Topic → Belongs on a different stack* options.  So, migration to a beta can't be done by popular vote.  Like us an SuperUser at the moment of writing.
2. Migrations to neonatal beta stacks are strongly discouraged.  The rationale is that a  neonatal stack needs time to figure out what it's about without interference from the outside.  I somewhat agree with this, but not completely agree.  A lot depends on the details of the neonatal stack.  As much as the neonatal stack needs to be left alone, it needs questions and traffic too.
   After 90 days, a beta stack is no longer neonatal by any measure.

It makes less sense in case of mature betas, nor it's strictly enforced.  It's a more of a guideline.  A mod can migrate anything to anywhere (at the risk of the aforementioned mod getting flak, of course).  The destination stack may reject the migration and advise the mod.

At the moment of writing, 70% of migrations out of EE.SE go to beta stacks.  Only 7% bounce back.